In Python, is it possible to control xmlns attributes ordering when printing
Say, I've a valid XML file. The root element may have various xmlns attributes, which are in a random order. I want to write out the same XML back but with a predictable order for xmlns attributes (say, sorted).
Neither minidom nor lxml seem to offer any controls over the xmlns attributes. minidom don't even seems to offer access to the xmlns attributes; lxml can gives access via the nsmap property, but the dict appears to be immutable.
I'm aware that attribute order doesn't affect the semantics of the XML. But my question is about whether any Python libraries provide this functionality. To wit, minidom does preserve the attribute order.
The relevance of this ordering is around file diffing: two semantically identical files may have different attribute orders when serialized, so a simple diff on them can't tell they're the same. Of course one can write a simple tool to compare the XML trees themselves, but think about committing those files in a Git repo: files will show up as changed only due to attribute order. That's the situation I'm trying to avoid: to read and write them back with attributes in a predictable order, before committing.
Is there any way out?

Text diffing XML will fail in so many ways that namespace ordering alone won't help.  You could canonicalize the XML first if you insist on using text diff'ing.  See also other options here.
